# Can't select TextView in either DesignTab nor is it displayed in the XML file

Tags: android, xml

I'm pretty new at this. The problem accurs right after I've created a project with a blank activity. On the screen appears a "Hello World!" TextView but this TextView isn't displayed in the XML File and I can't select it in the Designtab but in order to delete it I either need to select it in the Designtab or delete the code in the XML File. How can I do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Moi.png

This is a picture of the Preview Page in Android Studio with the XML Code to the left.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Go to res->layout->content main.xml file you can access it from that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the `content_main.xml` layout file, you should see the "Hello World" TextView. You are currently using the `include` tag to load a seperate xml file

Comment: This is it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard auto-generated code by Android Studio. In the **activity_main.xml** you have the code for the Toolbar and the FloatingActionButton and it is included another xml file **content_main.xml** where you put all the elements you want.